# Sum of three bijections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is one problem from my set theory course, which I can't solve. So here is the statement that has to be proven:
For every function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, there exist $3$ bijections $g_1, g_2$ and $g_3$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, such that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $$f(n) = g_1(n) + g_2(n) + g_3(n)$$
I know it's mostly about well-orderings, however I can't see how to use them.

Comment: What's wrong with letting $g_1(n)=g_2(n)=g_3(n)=\frac13 f(n)$?

Comment: $f$ is not said to be bijection and that could make $g_1, g_2, g_3$ not bijections too.

Comment: Oh, I overread that

Comment: Do you know if that proof is constructive?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56430/sum-of-three-bijections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose $g_1(n)$, $g_2(n)$ and $g_3(n)$ simultaneously in order of increasing $n$.

In a typical step you first choose $g_1(n)$ as the simplest rational not yet hit by $g_1$.
Then chose $g_2(n)$ as the simplest rational such that it is not yet hit by $g_2$, *and* $f(n)-g_1(n)-g_2(n)$ is not yet hit by $g_3$ (this is always possible because only finitely many values have been selected yet).

Alternate between the roles of $g_1$, $g_2$, and $g_3$ such that each of them will have the simplest unpicked rational picked infinitely often.

Comment: This method works with $3$ (as here) or more $g_i$. Is there a counterexample $f$ for two functions $g_1,g_2$?

Comment: @Hagen: Yes, in the MO question mfl linked in his comment: $f(0)=1$ and $f(n\ne 0)=0$.

Comment: I have a stupid question: if $f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=f(4)=1$ for instance... How come you can have three bijections $g_1, g_2, g_3$ that can give you this?

Comment: @Martigan: The construction depends on the domain being all of $\mathbb N$, not just $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: What means 'simplest'?

Comment: @brick: The one that comes first in your favorite enumeration of the rationals.

Comment: oh, this is where the well-ordering is been used right?

Comment: @brick: It's not enough that it's a well-order -- it needs to have order type $\omega$ such that you're sure everything gets picked eventually.